# How can I reset my dependency tree after ruining node_modules and package.json?

Tags: javascript, npm, create-react-app

I'm building an app using `create-react-app` and completely messed up my dependencies. I tried deleting `node-modules` and `package-lock.json`, but I messed up `package.json` too, so that didn't work. When I tried it and ran `npm start`, it gave me an error saying that `react-scripts` wasn't recognized as an internal or external command, operable program, or batch file.

I, stupidly, didn't commit/push anything to git before messing everything up, so I can't just do `git clone` and get back to an older version of my project that actually worked. I just want a way to get my project's environment looking like I just hit `create-react-app`. Is that possible without just literally doing that and copying/pasting all of my source code files?

Comment: You might try create-react-app again and copy over the package files then rerun node install there. Could be easier than recreating your files the other way around.

Comment: Since you mentioned git, I figured I'd mention that if you have a local git repository, you can reset back to a commit that was working. use `git log` to find the last working commit, then `git reset --hard {commithash}` to get back. Note that this will completely delete the work you've done since that commit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want exact same dependecies as create react up just copy its package.json, otherwise you cant do much thats why VCS are so important.